# Angular no puede acceder al médodo de la misma clase

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Estoy haciendo un `switch` para cambiar el `theme` de la vista, pero no accede al médodo de la misma clase, sale un error de que no existe

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(){
    var local = localStorage.getItem("theme") || "light-theme";
    this.loadStyle(local == "light-theme" ? "light-theme":"dark-theme");    
  }
  
  constructor() {}

  guri(styleName){
    switch(styleName){
      case "dark-theme": 
        return "assets/styles/style-dark.css";
      default:
        return "";
    }
  }

  loadStyle(styleName) {
    localStorage.setItem("theme", styleName);
    const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

    let themeLink = document.getElementById(
      'client-theme'
    ) as HTMLLinkElement;
    if (themeLink) {
      themeLink.href = this.guri(styleName);
    } else {
      const style = document.createElement('link');
      style.id = 'client-theme';
      style.rel = 'stylesheet';
      style.href = this.guri(styleName);

      head.appendChild(style);
    }
  }
}
```

**aside-card.html**

```
<li>
            <li class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <a href="#" (click)="stheme('light-theme')" class="light btn-light"><i class="fas fa-sun"></i></a>
                <a href="#" (click)="stheme('dark-theme')" class="dark btn-dark"><i class="fas fa-moon"></i></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

**app.html**

```
      <aside class="col-12 col-md-12 col-xl-3">
        <app-aside-card [loadStyle] = "loadStyle"></app-aside-card>
      </aside>
```

**aside-card.ts**

```
export class AsideCardComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() loadStyle;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  stheme(theme){
    this.loadStyle(theme);
  }
}
```

Comment: Puedes compartir aside-card.component ts y html?

Comment: @OscarLudick , actualizé la pregunta con los `html` y el `ts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La mejor forma de hacerlo es usando un servicio que se encargue de administrar el estilo de la aplicación. Pero vamos a solventar el problema actual.

El problema que tienes se debe a esto:

```
<app-aside-card [loadStyle] = "loadStyle"></app-aside-card>
```

Es válido hacer eso, el problema es que esa función que se pasa como parámetro cambia de contexto. Por eso la instrucción `this.guri(styleName);` produce error, porque en el contexto actual `guri()` no existe.

La solución a eso es usar una función lambda `() =>` , la función lambda se ejecutará dentro del contexto donde fue creada.

Se puede hacer una variable nueva `loadStyle2` y asignarle una función que ejecute la función `loadStyle()` original.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    
      loadStyle2 = (styleName) => this.loadStyle(styleName)
    
      // resto del código
    }
```

Luego se pasa esa variable al componente hijo:

```
<app-aside-card [loadStyle] = "loadStyle2"></app-aside-card>
```

[This javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/this)